# how to set 404 status code for angular 5 wildcard route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular5, angular4-router

i'm trying to set 404 status for my wildcard route using angular universal ssr, please suggest me the way to do it.
i already tried solution from

[404 status code](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-universal-handle-404-set-status-codes/)

Please help me out with it.

Comment: you are not able to set status code on backedn side or frontend side?

Comment: on front-end side

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
{
  path: '404',
  loadChildren: './routes/not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule'
}

{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '404'
}
```

Comment: yeah but i want to set 404 status code after redirecting to 'not-found'

Comment: Where you want to set status code `404` in router path? controller? or somewhere else?

Comment: i just don't know i'm confused  ,i just want 404 status in network when  angular redirect to 'not-found' route ,if know you how to do it please share your solution

Comment: Ohh, Actually you cannot, It will always come from server side, you can't do anything in this. Ask your backend team to send `404` status code and redirect from frontend accordingly

Comment: i just tried this solution but it's not working,https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-universal-handle-404-set-status-codes/

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code